# How to make Mouse Look work in the logic bricks editor in UPBGE 0.3 Alpha?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have the following bricks in the editor:

[image: Mouse Look]

But nothing happens when I move the mouse in the play mode.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a <kbd>Mouse</kbd> sensor with the type <kbd>Movement</kbd> instead of an Always sensor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! It works!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I am having an issue with very jaggy/sometimes not moving at all - does anyone has a clue?
I used the exact same setup and it works in Blender 2.79 BGE, while doesn't work in UPBGE 0.3.1.